# how to create an executable jar file from an folder

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have taken an executable jar file from server to my local system and then I have unrar it through win rar and then I have made some changes in the .class file now i again want to make executable jar file of the folder that get created when I initially unrar it please advise how can i create executable jar file again

folks please advise with context to creating an executable jar file

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-JAR-File perhaps

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that all your project file's are in folder named `MyApp`

then

1. open command prompt
2. navigate to directory where `MyApp` is placed using `cd`
3. execute command `jar cvf MyApp.jar MyApp`

---

**EDIT**
(*To make this `jar` executable:*)

create a file named `MANIFEST.MF` and put it in `META-INF` folder

> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.somepackage.MyApp
```

OR you can simply use Launch4j to wrap up your program into an executable: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: please advise command to create an executable jar file

Comment: please see my edited question for that